# How to create one header and another as sub-header row in csv file

Tags: pyspark

I have one csv which has following record:

[enter image description here][https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvRcK.png]

Sorry I am not able to build this table in stack exchange that's why I pasted the image

So Can I create pyspark dataframe for above output

I have used below code

```
df = spark.read.csv('ab.csv', header=True)
```

but this is making only first line as header.

How can we have header under header

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
data = [('xx1', 'sam, 12),('smoth, 'bravo', 17),('nm', 'nam', 89)]
    
header = ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Age']
sub_header = ['-', '-', '-']
    
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, header)
    
# Write the data into CSV file with header and sub-header rows
df.write.option('header', ','.join(header)).option('lineSep', '\n' + ','.join(sub_header) + '\n').csv('path')
```